# How to move elements from one linked list to another in order

Tags: c, linked-list

What i need to do is to copy the linked list list1 already filled with these values:

```
0000001  3  
0000002  2  
0000003  1  
0000004  1
```

and paste them with the function CreateMenuList() into another list called list2, so that every element of list2 has the members of list1 matching a particular number, the output of ViewAllMenu() should be this:

```
1    
 0000004
 0000003
2
 0000002
3
 0000001
```

For now i've just wrote this basic concept:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct Order { 
    char code[8];
    int menu;
};

typedef struct NodeO {
    struct Order order;
    struct NodeO *next;
} TNode;

typedef TNode * NodeO;

struct Menu {
    int code;
    NodeO orders_list;
};

typedef struct NodeM {
    struct Menu menu;
    struct NodeM * next;
} TNodeM;

typedef TNodeM * NodeM;

//this function is for creating nodes for list1
NewOrder(struct Order p, NodeO * pp)
{
    NodeO temp;

    temp = malloc(sizeof(struct NodeO));
    temp->order = p;
    temp->next = *pp;

    *pp = temp;

}

void main()
{
    NodeO list1 = NULL;
    NodeM list2 = NULL;

    //supposing list1 is already filled
    CreateMenuList(list1,list2);
    ViewAllMenu(lista2);
}
```

Supposing we've already filled `list1` using a function that calls `NewOrder` using stdin, what the function `CreateMenuList` should do to modify `list2` and creating `n` members to store all orders matching the menu? `ViewAllMenu` is not really a problem, cause it should be a simple while loop with `printf`.

Comment: I see a `malloc`, but I don't see a `free` anywhere. Kabooom!

Comment: `void main()` is ancient.

Comment: `temp = (NodeO)malloc(sizeof(struct NodeO))` is missing a `;` and the type cast is needless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are all the functions needed:

```
void Load(NodeO * p)
{
  FILE *f;
  struct Order s;
  char * buffer = malloc(sizeof(struct Order));

  if(!(f=fopen("test.txt", "r")))
   {
    perror("Errore");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
   }

  while(fgets(buffer,sizeof(struct Order), f))
  {
      if(sscanf(buffer, "%s%d", s.code, &s.menu) == 2 )
      {
        NewOrder(s,p);
      }
  }
  free(buffer);
  fclose(f);
}

void InsertOrder(NodeM * pp, struct Order p)
{
  NodeM  s;

    s = *pp;

    while(s != NULL && (s->menu.code != p.menu))
    s = s->next;

    if( s == NULL)
    {
    s = (NodeM)malloc(sizeof(TNodeM));
           s->next = *pp;
               *pp = s;
      s->menu.code = p.menu;
      s->menu.list = NULL;
    }

    NewOrder(p, &s->menu.list);
}

void CreateMenuList(NodeO p, NodeM * pp)
{
   while(p != NULL)
   {
      InsertOrder(pp, p->order);
      p = p->next;
   }
}



void ViewAllMenu(NodeM p)
{
  NodeO s;
  while(p != NULL)
  {
    s = p->menu.list;
    printf("%d\n", p->menu.code);
    while(s != NULL)
    {
      printf("\t%s\n", s->order.code);
      s = s->next;
    }
   p = p->next;
  }

}
```